# Why do we need to use package.json?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, websocket, package.json

I am trying to learn web socket with JavaScript  to this [site](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/), but I do not understand something that why I need to use **package.json**. This is my package.json file code:

```
`{
  "name": "module-name",
  "version": "10.3.1",
  "description": "An example module to illustrate the usage of a package.json",
  "author": "Your Name <you.name@example.org>",
  "contributors": [{
  "name": "Foo Bar",
  "email": "foo.bar@example.com"
}],
  "bin": {
  "module-name": "./bin/module-name"
},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "vows --spec --isolate",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "predeploy": "echo im about to deploy",
    "postdeploy": "echo ive deployed",
    "prepublish": "coffee --bare --compile --output lib/foo src/foo/*.coffee"
  },
  "main": "lib/foo.js",
  "repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "https://github.com/nodejitsu/browsenpm.org"
},
  "bugs": {
  "url": "https://github.com/nodejitsu/browsenpm.org/issues"
},
  "keywords": [
  "nodejitsu",
  "example",
  "browsenpm"
],
  "dependencies": {
    "primus": "*",
    "async": "~0.8.0",
    "express": "4.2.x",
    "winston": "git://github.com/flatiron/winston#master",
    "bigpipe": "bigpipe/pagelet",
    "plates": "https://github.com/flatiron/plates/tarball/master"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vows": "^0.7.0",
    "assume": "<1.0.0 || >=2.3.1 <2.4.5 || >=2.5.2 <3.0.0",
    "pre-commit": "*"
  },
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "private": true,
  "publishConfig": {
  "registry": "https://your-private-hosted-npm.registry.nodejitsu.com"
},
  "subdomain": "foobar",
  "analyze": true,
  "license": "MIT"
}`
```

But I do not understand why I need to use it. I tried to find on google but can not find something useful. One more thing, if I create `package.json` then why I need to write **dependencies**?

Comment: This should help: https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/npm/what-is-the-file-package-json

Comment: Dependencies make it so that if you take it to another machine or server, you know exactly what is required to make it run.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a specific programming question, but rather a request for education which is outside the scope of StackOverflow

Answer (score 9):

You do not NEED package.json. However, you will most likely want it. As you make larger applications using node.js, you will find that using other people's code is the best solution vs. writing the same thing yourself.

npm has lots of packages that people want to use over and over again. package.json provides a simple way for people to keep track of packages they use in their application.