# Should I rely on package.json or keep version control on my node modules?

Tags: node.js, react-native, version-control, node-modules, package.json

Recently, I am working on react-native projects. I have done an old project and I would like to clone it into a new project so that I could develop somethings new on top of the old version but not affect the old project itself.

The thing I figured out is that every time I do `npm install` with the same package.json, the `node_modules` folder installed may not be the same. This may because we have prefix, `^` or `~`, in front of some of the modules' version. Also, the modules installed also have their own dependencies that may be updated by itself.

Therefore, it comes to the problem. Should I use package.json to do the version control?

According to here: [Why do we need to use package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790750/why-do-we-need-to-use-package-json), it said `package.json provides a simple way for people to keep track of packages they use in their application.`

However, how can I do the version control with my project if `package.json` always updates the project by itself without concerning about the compatibility of different modules.

The only solution comes to my mind is: We should do the version control on the node_modules. If that is the case, is package.json becomes meaningless?

So, I would like to know what is the industrial practice for doing version control on `node_modules` and `package.json` related projects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a version of NPM prior to 5 then you should look into [NPM Shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap).  This locks down the versions of the NPM modules you are currently using.  Once committed to the project if anybody else `npm install` they get the exact versions specified in shrink wrap.

> **npm-shrinkwrap**
>   Lock down dependency versions for publication

With the release of [NPM 5](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/161276872334/npm5-is-now-npmlatest) it automatically creates an `package-lock.json` file, similar to shrinkwrap, when you run `npm install` by default.  You should commit the lock or shinkwrap files to your SCM.

You should also look into [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/).  Yarn comes out of the box with a `yarn.lock` file which works in the same way but with additional performance speeds and offline capabilities.

> Using a detailed, but concise, lockfile format, and a deterministic algorithm for installs, Yarn is able to guarantee that an install that worked on one system will work exactly the same way on any other system.

If you already have a project and `node_modules` folder and wish to change to Yarn without installing all the modules again, then you can run `yarn import` which will generate a lock file based of your current node modules folders.

Both the above solutions mean you should not require to add your `node_modules` to an SCM - doing so can add other complexities when users on different platforms (windows, mac, etc) are working on the project.  Lock files should be committed with your project.

Comment: Also, since npm 5, npm also have a lockfile ([blog post](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/161276872334/npm5-is-now-npmlatest)).

Comment: NPM 5 also uses lock files by default, in a similar manner to Yarn (`package-lock.json`).

Comment: @Kerumen: Beat me by 5 seconds :p

Comment: I see but my current project is not locked by `NPM Shrinkwrap` or `Yarn`. If I do `yarn install` now, it will still automatically install the incompatible `node_module` and override my stable `node_module`. May I know how to solve this?

Comment: You can run `npm shrinkwrap` now, it will lock to versions you have installed.

Comment: OK, updated answer again, you can run `yarn import` to generate the `yarn.lock` file